# Make Special Characters Appear Bold

Tags: html, css, fonts, bold

I have text that contains non-alphanumeric characters that I want to appear as bold.

```
<span style="font-weight:bold">+/-</span>
```

However, I guess because of the simplicity of the characters making them bold does not really do anything as they look the same as the adjacent non-bold characters. I'm using the default font so is it possible the font does not have a bold representation for non-alphanumerics? How can I get these characters to appear as bold? TIA.

Comment: You could use a bold font and [unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range)

Comment: Thanks. What font would provide the same appearance but in bold?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `<b>` tag. Something like that.

```
<b>+/-</b>
```

It may solve the problem.